# Trustpilot Api - Get Private Product Review always returns Unauthorised response status

Tags: api, review, unauthorized, trustpilot

I hope someone can help me.

I am trying to retrieve a Product Review for a product using the Trustpilot Api's and am having some success but not getting the results I would expect.

The approach I have taken is as follows:

1. Get an OAUTH2 token - (Returns a successful response)
2. Retrieve my business units from a config file and for each business unit get the product reviews using the endpoint: `https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/business-units/{business-unit}/review?token={OAUTH2 token from step 1}` - (Returns a successful response)
3. For each product review I attempt to retrieve the product review detail.  For this I have a couple of options.

   (i)  Each product review has meta-links and so I can get the product review using the corresponding meta-link and tagging the apikey on e.g. `https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/reviews/1234567890abcdefg?apikey={apikey}` where the apikey is the one provided up when I registered for a developer account - (Returns a successful response)

   (ii) Call the endpoint as documented in the developers.trustpilot.api website (https://developers.trustpilot.com/product-reviews-api#get-private-product-review) : `https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/{reviewId}` - (Returns an Unauthorised status code)

For option (ii) above I have tried multiple ways of passing the apikey (according to the documentation, the endpoint requires the apikey as authorisation.

I am using C# as the language for accessing the Trustpilot apis so the following snippets are how I have tried to call the method.

1. Set the GetProductReview endpoint as follows:

```
    var url = $"https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/" + review.Id.ToString();        
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
       var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
       client.BaseAddress = uri;

       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new system.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("apikey", apiKey);

       try
       {
         var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
             .
             .
             .
```

In the above code snippet, the apikey is passed in to the method and passed to the endpoint as a RequestHeader value.

2. Set the endpoint as follows:

```
var url = $"https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/" + review.Id + $"?apikey={apiKey}";
```

and call the HttpClient as follows:

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
    var uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);
    client.BaseAddress = uri;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    try
    {
      var response = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
          .
          .
          .
```

In both cases I receive an HttpStatus 401 - Unauthorized.

The documentation indicates that I should pass the apikey (which I have done in two different ways).

I have also tried calling the endpoint replacing the `?apikey={apiKey}` with `?token={token}` in case the documentation is incorrect and requires a token.

Additionally, I have also tried passing the token as a RequestHeader value and receieve the same result (Unauthoirised)

I would really like to use the endpoint:

```
https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/{review}
```

as this returns more information (for example the sku which would allow me to get access back to the product).

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for the `/v1/private/product-reviews/{reviewId}` endpoint is indeed **incorrect**, since it actually requires a `Business user OAuth Token` instead of an `API Key`.

In this case, you have [two options](https://developers.trustpilot.com/authentication) (and the first one you have used before for the `/v1/private/business-units/{businessUnitId}/reviews` endpoint):

1. You can pass the access token in the query string: `/v1/private/product-reviews/{reviewId}?token={token}`. You mentioned you have tried this. Maybe it did not work for you because your token expired before you tried this approach. Can you try again after [refreshing the token](https://developers.trustpilot.com/tutorials/authentication-via-api)?
2. You can also pass the access token as a [`Bearer authorization header`](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/):

   ```
   var url = $"https://api.trustpilot.com/v1/private/product-reviews/{review.Id.ToString()}";        
   using (var client = new HttpClient())
   {
       ...

       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

       ...
   }
   ```

In any case, you caught an error in the documentation that should be fixed soon. As a rule of thumb, all private endpoints (the ones that have `/private/` in the path) require a `Business user OAuth Token`.

**EDIT**: The documentation for the `/v1/private/product-reviews/{reviewId}` endpoint [has been fixed](https://developers.trustpilot.com/product-reviews-api#get-private-product-review). Now it shows that a `Business user OAuth Token` is required.

Comment: Thanks Alberto.  I have implemented your suggestion but now receive a NotFound status code.  I can only assume that the review Id expected is different for the `/v1/private/product-reviews/{review}` endpoint is different to the one for the `api.trustpilot.com/v1/reviews/{review}` endpoint and the review cannot be found for that review id.  Thank you for the answer ... I will mark it as correct.

Comment: @JulianHolling oh, I had not noticed this before. `/v1/private/business-units/{businessUnitId}/reviews` returns **SERVICE** reviews for a given business unit. But then you are trying to get a **PRODUCT** review by using this other endpoint (that's why you are getting not found). You should use this instead: https://developers.trustpilot.com/service-reviews-api#get-private-review to get an individual service review. The authorization is also based on token in this case.

Comment: @JulianHolling If you really want product reviews, then the first endpoint is wrong (because `/v1/private/business-units/{businessUnitId}/reviews` this is for service reviews), you should use this one to get a list of **PRODUCT** reviews: https://developers.trustpilot.com/product-reviews-api#get-private-product-reviews (`/v1/private/product-reviews/business-units/{businessUnitId}/reviews`)

Comment: Alberto - thanks you very much for the feedback ... I will give this a try and comment later on my findings.

Comment: @JulianHolling It's a bit misleading that we have `reviews` in the path sometimes indicating service reviews, and other times product reviews. I advise you to check the section from https://developers.trustpilot.com/ to make sure you are only using endpoints for product reviews (if this is what you really want). That's the section for product reviews: https://developers.trustpilot.com/product-reviews-api, and that's the one for service reviews: https://developers.trustpilot.com/service-reviews-api

Comment: Alberto - thanks for clarifying.  It turns out, when I call the "service" reviews endpoint, I can see the reviews for the company I work for i.e. a general review of the company (even though people are discussing the benefits / drawbacks of particular products).  However, when I call the product review endpoint, there are no reviews so I need to clarify with the company which reviews they would like to see.  Thanks very much for all your help.

Comment: Oh, I see. Glad to help :)